# How do I measure a PT100/1000 with a Arduino over I2C?

Tags: adc, temperature, rtd

How do I measure one or more PT100/1000 (PTC Resistor) with a Arduino/ATmega328 over I2C?
Are there any ready microchips? Do I need to construct my own circuit? If so, are there any ready schematics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen some ADC's from Analog specifically for RTD sensors with I2C interface - check their parametric table. Other manufacturers probably also have these.

Also, you can use any I2C ADC with differential input for that.

Schematics will be in datasheet :-)

Comment: This not answer the question.

Comment: @DanielGrillo Actually, it is. An I2C ADC is practically the only way to read an analog thermistor via I2C. (aside from programming an mcu to act like an I2C ADC).

Comment: Answer or not, two years out is a funny time to be bringing it up

Comment: @ScottSeidman  Standards change.  The bar raises.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, apparently every two years!